# Bulk Exchange Rate Call

Tags: curated-data, finance

I have a function which gives me the exchange rate of `GBP` to `USD` as follows:

```
exchangeRate = 
  Quiet@QuantityMagnitude@
     CurrencyConvert[Quantity[1, DatedUnit["GBP", DateList[#]]], 
      DatedUnit["USD", DateList[#]]] &;
```

The function works fine for single dates:
`exchangeRate["02-Jan-2017"]`
but is too slow for a sequence of dates:
`exchangeRate /@ DateRange["02-Jan-2017", "31-Jan-2017"]` since it is pulling one rate at a time. Can someone help me create a function that will work for a range of dates with a single call.

Comment: You may see a little increase in speed if you use the `BusinessDay` option in your `DateRange`.  Also, the arguments of `CurrencyConvert` can be lists, so you can pass all of your quantities and dates at once, which may give you a little boost.

Comment: Is there another function to perform this conversion. Is there a way to get historical dates from `FinancialData`?